# What is the c# equivalent to Java's GeneralPath?

Tags: java, c#

Say I need to covert [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Graphics/Shape/Create_shape_with_GeneralPath_in_Java.htm) java program into a C# program.

What is the C# equivalent to java's `GeneralPath` found in the package `java.awt.geom`?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent (if using `System.Drawing`) is:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
```

You can do lines as so:

```
var gp1 = new GraphicsPath();
gp1.AddLines(new Point[]
{
    new Point(50, 10),
    new Point(70, 80),
    new Point(90, 40),
    new Point(10, 40),
    new Point(50, 80)
});
gp1.CloseFigure();
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), gp1);
```

`GraphisPath` does not have a Quadratic Bezier, but you can fit it in to a Cubic Bezier. Here is an extension to do that:

```
public static class GraphicsPathExtensions
{
    public static void AddQuadraticBezier(
        this GraphicsPath graphicsPath, PointF start, PointF ctrl, PointF end)
    {
        var c1 = new PointF(start.X, start.Y);
        c1.X += (2.0f / 3.0f) * (ctrl.X - start.X);
        c1.Y += (2.0f / 3.0f) * (ctrl.Y - start.Y);

        var c2 = new PointF(ctrl.X, ctrl.Y);
        c2.X += (end.X - ctrl.X) / 3.0f;
        c2.Y += (end.Y - ctrl.Y) / 3.0f;

        graphicsPath.AddBezier(start, c1, c2, end);
    }

    public static void AddQuadraticBezier(
        this GraphicsPath graphicsPath, Point start, Point ctrl, Point end)
    {
        graphicsPath.AddQuadraticBezier(
            new PointF(start.X, start.Y),
            new PointF(ctrl.X, ctrl.Y),
            new PointF(end.X, end.Y));
    }
}
```

You could call it as so:

```
var gp6 = new GraphicsPath();
gp6.AddQuadraticBezier(
    new Point(120, 180),
    new Point(150, 120),
    new Point(180, 180));
gp6.CloseFigure();
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), gp6);
```

Here is an example of all of them:

```
var gp7 = new GraphicsPath();
gp7.AddBezier(
    new Point(220, 150),
    new Point(240, 130),
    new Point(280, 160),
    new Point(300, 140));
gp7.AddLine(
    new Point(300, 140),
    new Point(300, 180));
gp7.AddQuadraticBezier(
    new Point(300, 180),
    new Point(260, 160),
    new Point(220, 180));
gp7.CloseFigure();
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), gp7);
```

Comment: I don't see nay `LineTo()` or `MoveTo()` in `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath`

Comment: @user366312 -- added example of doing lines. Not all the calls don't match up one-for-one, but can accomplish the same thing

Comment: @user366312 -- added the most complex one. That should show you how to do everything. You'll notice "overlapping" points, that's typical of `GraphicsPath`. No idea why they didn't do it the typical way (moveTo, lineTo, curveTo, etc).